# Pseudo-random regex-searchable function

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, strings, pseudo-random-generators

Let $L$ be the set of strings of length $n$ (say $n=400$, for example). Let $N = \{0,1,\dots,|L|-1\}$. I am looking for a function $f : N \to L$ with the following properties:

- $f$ is efficiently computable
- $f$ is a bijection
- $f$ is pseudorandom (not necessarily cryptographically)
- Given some interval $[a,b]$ and a regular expression $r$, we can efficiently test if there exists $n \in N \cap[a,b]$ such that $f(n)$ satisfies $r$.

Does such a $f$ exist?

The tricky part is finding a function that satisfies both the second and fourth requirement.

One thought I had was to define $f(x) = c + px \pmod{|L|}$ for some constant $c$ and prime $p$. This satisfies the first three properties, but I don't think its regex searchable.

(The motivation is that such a $f$ would amount to a searchable library of Babel.)

Comment: What do you mean by pseudorandom? Looks random? How about the following: pick a permutation $\pi$ on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and for each $1 \leq i \leq n$ pick a permutation $\sigma_i$ on the alphabet. Replace $x_1\ldots x_n$ by $\sigma_1(x_{\pi(1)}) \ldots \sigma_n( x_{\pi(n)} )$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, looks random. For example, half of the bits should change (on average).

Comment: How about my suggestion, then?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I'm still trying to understand it. How do you regex search it?

Comment: Just like you regex search when $f$ is the identity function. You haven't explained how you do that, but the same method should work in this case as well.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Wait, it appears your example isn't pseudo-random, because if you change one letter in the input, only one letter in the output changes, right?

Comment: Unless you define what pseudorandom means for you, it is impossible to tell what you mean by it. Please try to define what you mean by pseudorandom. Be as explicit as possible. We cannot read your mind.

Comment: If there are any other "obvious" assumptions, that for example makes regex searching possible, please include them as well. Nothing is obvious for us. You have to state everything to the fullest extent.